# Can PlatformView on flutter help build AdMob BannerAd widget for flutter?

Tags: flutter, admob

The firebase_admob plugin has support for banner ad which can be placed only on a fixed set of positions (top,bottom) because its just putting native view in top of the flutters activity/ViewController. Is it possible no to export BannerAd as a widget using PlatformView?

Or is it somehow possible right now to add banner ad inside a scrollable widget of flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try thís https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_native_admob. It uses exact PlatformView as you expect. But the limitation is not supporting iOS yet.

> Warning: The plugin is based on Flutter **PlatformView** (AndroidView) to
>   create a custom widget from Native View. Therefore, only Android is
>   supported at the moment. For iOS, wait for Flutter team to implement
>   **iOSView** equivalent.